# Df Headers: Insert a full year of header rows at end of month and fill non populated months with zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Afternoon All,

Test Data as at 30 Mar 2019:

```
Test_Data = [
                ('Index', ['Year_Month','Done_RFQ','Not_Done_RFQ','Total_RFQ']),
                ('0', ['2019-01',10,20,30]),
                ('1', ['2019-02', 10, 20, 30]),
                ('2', ['2019-03', 20, 40, 60]),
             ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Test_Data))
print(df)

          Index        0        1        2
0    Year_Month  2019-01  2019-02  2019-03
1      Done_RFQ       10       10       20
2  Not_Done_RFQ       20       20       40
3     Total_RFQ       30       30       60
```

Desired output as at 31 Mar 2019

[image]

Desired output as at 30 Apr 2019

[image]

As each month progresses the unformatted df will have an additional column of data

I'd like to:

a. Replace headers in the existing df, note there will only be four columns in March, then 5 in April....13 in Dec:

```
df.columns = ['Report_Mongo','Month_1','Month_2','Month_3','Month_4','Month_5','Month_6','Month_7','Month_8','Month_9','Month_10','Month_11','Month_12']
```

b. As we progress through the year zero valaues would be replaced with data. The challenge is to determine how many months have passed and only update non populated columns with data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign columns by length of original columns and [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
c = ['Report_Mongo','Month_1','Month_2','Month_3','Month_4','Month_5','Month_6',
     'Month_7','Month_8','Month_9','Month_10','Month_11','Month_12']

df.columns = c[:len(df.columns)]
df = df.reindex(c, axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
   Report_Mongo  Month_1  Month_2  Month_3  Month_4  Month_5  Month_6  \
0    Year_Month  2019-01  2019-02  2019-03        0        0        0   
1      Done_RFQ       10       10       20        0        0        0   
2  Not_Done_RFQ       20       20       40        0        0        0   
3     Total_RFQ       30       30       60        0        0        0   

   Month_7  Month_8  Month_9  Month_10  Month_11  Month_12  
0        0        0        0         0         0         0  
1        0        0        0         0         0         0  
2        0        0        0         0         0         0  
3        0        0        0         0         0         0
```

Alternative is create header with months periods, advantage is only numeric data in all rows:

```
#set columns by first row
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
#remove first row and create index by first column
df = df.iloc[1:].set_index('Year_Month')
#convert columns to month periods 
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_period('m')
#reindex to full year
df = df.reindex(pd.period_range(start='2019-01',end='2019-12',freq='m'),axis=1,fill_value=0)
print (df)
             2019-01 2019-02 2019-03  2019-04  2019-05  2019-06  2019-07  \
Year_Month                                                                 
Done_RFQ          10      10      20        0        0        0        0   
Not_Done_RFQ      20      20      40        0        0        0        0   
Total_RFQ         30      30      60        0        0        0        0   

              2019-08  2019-09  2019-10  2019-11  2019-12  
Year_Month                                                 
Done_RFQ            0        0        0        0        0  
Not_Done_RFQ        0        0        0        0        0  
Total_RFQ           0        0        0        0        0
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael

Comment: @PeterLucas - You are welcome! Added another slution, maybe also help.

Comment: Ah great. Thanks again